# R - Verifying That A Column Only Has Certain Values

Tags: r, validation, verification

I am trying to figure out how to verify that that columns of a spreadsheet only contain a predetermined set of values.  Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

To provide an example, I am using the following method to determine that the number of columns is correct.

```
if(!ncol(data_read) == 9){
    print("There are not 9 columns in this file")
    return(FALSE)
} else if{
  OTHER PARAMETERS HERE (such as the one I'm trying to figure out)
  }

   return(TRUE}
 }
```

Comment: `length(unique(data_read$column))` or `sum(!duplicated(data_read$column))` should give you an idea of how many unique set of values exist in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valid_values <- c(1, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 2), b = c(2, 3, 4))

all(df$a %in% valid_values)
[1] TRUE
all(df$b %in% valid_values)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Could I place this in an in statement using the ! operator?  eg. if any value is not in the valid values return false.

Comment: yes just put it in brackets: `if(!(all(df$b %in% valid_values)))`

Comment: For some reason it is returning a 'false' where it should be returning a 'true'. The values are strings if that makes a difference

Comment: @MichaelLink could you post an example of data where you get unexpected output?